# Magic method to assign variable in Ipython

Tags: ipython

Assign variable in bash script

```
$ d=$(date)
$ echo $d
Fri 18 Oct 2019 04:31:03 PM CST
```

However,when it come to ipython terminal,

```
In [25]: !d=$(date)

In [26]: !echo $d


In [27]:
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "magic method". 
If you want to run a bash command in your Jupyter/iPython notebook, you can use Python's subprocess module. In this case the following should work:

```
import subprocess

d = subprocess.Popen('date', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
d = d.communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
d=!date
d
```

or

```
d=!date
print(d)
```

it returns a list:

```
['lun 16 nov 2020 13:13:24 CET']
```

if you just want the string, try:

```
d[0]
```